# failed to solve (exit code: 100). Error in docker

Tags: python, windows, docker, dockerfile

This is the first time I have experience with docker, and I don't quite understand what exactly is happening, but when I enter the command in the terminal:

```
docker-compose --env-file config\config.env up --build
```

The terminal after 3 minutes of some processes gives me this error:

**failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip python-dev build-essential python3-venv ffmpeg]: exit code: 100**

I am using Windows operating system and here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

ENV PYTHONFAULTHANDLER=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
ENV PYTHONHASHSEED=random
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PIP_NO_CACHE_DIR=off
ENV PIP_DISABLE_PIP_VERSION_CHECK=on
ENV PIP_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT=100

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip python-dev build-essential python3-venv ffmpeg

RUN mkdir -p /code
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
RUN apk add --update linux-headers

CMD ["bash"]
```

I will be very glad if you help me because I have already killed the whole month to understand what the problem is

I entered the `RUN apk add --update linux-headers into my file`
, but it didn't give results, before that my file worked, but it was constantly rebooting in the docker, because of which I couldn't start, I decided to restart the docker and see what happens, but now I have this error.

Comment: The "exit code: 100" message essentially just says "it didn't work"; do you have the complete error message?  The `python` image will come with Python preinstalled and you don't need any of the Debian Python packages you cite.  There's also a potential caching issue running `apt-get update` and `install` in two separate `RUN` lines.

Comment: In addition I am a Little confused why you are using apt and apk. That most likely won't work as you will only have one package manager depending on which distro is used as base

Comment: So I just tried this and it works except the apk part that breaks as expected. Can you actually connect to the package repo mirrors from your box?

Comment: that is, should I delete the apk and apt lines?

Answer (score 1):

You should replace `python-dev` with `python3-dev` in dockerfile. Then reinstall your images in docker images (delete all and run

```
docker-compose --env-file config\config.env up --build
```

again)